# Is it possible to delete an object's property in PHP?

Tags: php, object

If I have an `stdObject` say, `$a`.

Sure there's no problem to assign a new property, `$a`,

```
$a->new_property = $xyz;
```

But then I want to remove it, so `unset` is of no help here.

So,

```
$a->new_property = null;
```

is kind of it. But is there a more 'elegant' way?

Comment: Can you post code how you tried with unset  ? In mine sense unset should work.But possibly you duplicating the context

Comment: really not sure how unset() is more elegant than = null, but may be that's just me

Answer (score 510, accepted):

```
unset($a->new_property);
```

This works for array elements, variables, and object attributes.

Example:

```
$a = new stdClass();

$a->new_property = 'foo';
var_export($a);  // -> stdClass::__set_state(array('new_property' => 'foo'))

unset($a->new_property);
var_export($a);  // -> stdClass::__set_state(array())
```

Comment: n.b. It is not possible to directly unset a property that has an integer key. e.g. `$o=(object)array('a','b','c');`  (You have to convert the object (back) to an array even to simply _access_ such properties!)

Comment: @danorton, the question is about an `object`, not an `array`. For an array, you need to [splice](http://ca3.php.net/array_splice) it.

Comment: @YanickRochon, my comment is about an `object`, not an `array`. ;-)

Comment: @danorton why would someone, in their right mind, convert an `array` into an `object`? It just makes no sense (even if PHP allows it). I will not encorage and spread bad programming habits by commenting on this :) No offense.

Comment: @YanickRochon this can make sense if you want to merge the properties of two objects (that have no method, they just are used as storage medium): in this case, the fastest and simplest route is to convert both objects into arrays to apply array_replace_recursive() and back onto objects afterwards. As to why someone would use an object to only store properties, this often happens in applications fetching from databases such as MySQL the records as an object instead of an array (using standard functions such as mysql_fetch_object()).

Comment: @danorton FYI, since 7.2 you can do `unset($o->{0});` or `$k = 0; unset($o->$k);`.

Comment: they not meant to convert an array to object (wich make no sense at all), but to convert associative array to object

Comment: @YanickRochon, it makes sense if you want a struct-like object, and you want an easy initialization – in that case, I regularly do `$x = (object) [ 'prop1' => $val1, ... ]`

Answer (score 68):

This also works specially if you are looping over an object.

```
unset($object[$key])
```

#### Update

Newer versions of PHP throw fatal error `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Object as array` as mentioned by @CXJ . In that case you can use brackets instead

```
unset($object->{$key})
```

Comment: Could you specify which "newer" versions are described? For me, with PHP 7.1 `unset($object[$key])` works and `unset($object->{$key})` does not (to be more precise, `unset($object['literal_key'])` and `unset($object->{'literal_key'})`). PS Hm, I may be wrong, though, in thinking the thing I'm editing is an object, not an array

Comment: Does not unset a property from a collection of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Set an element  to null just set the value of the element to null the element still exists

unset an element means remove the element
it works for array, stdClass objects  user defined classes and also for any variable

```
<?php
    $a = new stdClass();
    $a->one = 1;
    $a->two = 2;
    var_export($a);
    unset($a->one);
    var_export($a);
    
    class myClass
    {
        public $one = 1;
        public $two = 2;
    }
    
    $instance = new myClass();
    var_export($instance);
    unset($instance->one);
    var_export($instance);
    
    $anyvariable = 'anyValue';
    var_export($anyvariable);
    unset($anyvariable);
    var_export($anyvariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works if you are looping over an object.

```
unset($object->$key);
```

No need to use brackets.

Comment: This question does not add anything new in comparison with @YannickRochon's one.

Comment: This question does not add anything new in comparison with @YannickRochon's one.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me in a loop

```
$remove = array(
    "market_value",
    "sector_id"
);

foreach($remove as $key){
    unset($obj_name->$key);
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses `array` but the question was about `stdClass` objects.  What you said isn't wrong, but irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is an old topic.

Just as the others mention it, you can use

```
unset($a->new_poperty);
```

Additionally, just as @Sajjad Ashraf mention, you can use

```
$a->new_property = null;
```

In order to clean data of "new_property" instead of delete the whole property.

It was help me when worked with dynamic properties and iterations. Because if I used "unset" I got an error like "my_property is unset"

PD: Sorry for my english