# Removing an array from a session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, array-push

I am building a shopping cart using session variables. I can push the array to the session array like this:

```
//initialize session cart array
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
//store the stuff in an array
$items  = array($item, $qty);
//add the array to the cart
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $items);
```

So far, so good. The problem is in removing an item from the cart. When I try to use this, I get a array to string conversion error.

```
//remove an array from the cart
$_SESSION['cart'] = array_diff($_SESSION['cart'], $items);
```

To clarify, the question here is why is the above statement creating an array to string conversion error?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600750/is-it-possible-to-delete-an-objects-property-in-php

Comment: any reason to use array_push over `$_SESSION['cart'][]= $items;`

Comment: Not so fast -- not a duplicate at all. Check your info before posting.

Comment: use the item id as the key and unset that

Comment: Wouldn't $_SESSION['cart'][]= $items; simply overwrite the same cell each time it was invoked?

Comment: nope it increments using the next free id. i see now its the first thing mentioned on the array_push page

Comment: Is there an advantage to using that method over array_push()?

Comment: "    Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function. "

Comment: Do a `print_r(array_diff($_SESSION['cart'], $items));` I dont think that `array_diff` is generating what you hoped it would.

Comment: I can see how using the item ID as a key would work with only one value, i.e. qty as in $item=>$qty, but what if I decided to add more to the array, like $item = array($item=>$qty, $qty, $price, $descr)? Would unset then delete the entire array or just $qty?

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'][$item]= array($qty,$descrip,$size,$colour);`

Comment: Aaaah. I like that approach. That seems practical.

Comment: explained in answer below

Comment: How about storing an array of objects rather than array of arrays. Its a whole lot easier to understand and read the code when you come back in a few weeks to fix something,

Comment: Don't you have to serialize the object to store it in a session variable?

Comment: No serialize necessary. $_SESSION is just like any other array and is automatcially serialized by PHP when it saves $_SESSION to a file.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing an array of objects like this. In my opinion it is a lots easier to read the code this way than addressing arrays within arrays

```
$item = new stdClass();
$item->id = 99;
$item->qty = 1;
$item->descr = 'An Ice Cream';
$item->price = 23.45;

$_SESSION['cart'][$item->id] = $item;
```

To remove an items from the cart

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item]);
```

To re-access the items data

```
echo $_SESSION['cart'][$item]->id;
echo $_SESSION['cart'][$item]->desc;
echo $_SESSION['cart'][$item]->price;
```

Or even

```
$item = $_SESSION['cart'][$item];
echo $item->id;
echo $item->desc;
echo $item->price;
```

Or even better

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $obj ) {
    echo $id ' = ' $obj->descr ' and costs ' . $obj->price;
}
```

To change existing info

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item]->qty += 1;
```

or

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item]->qty = $newQty;
```

Comment: Can you add methods to your object and still store it as a session variable?

Comment: No I am afraid not. But if you actually created an class you can save the properties of the object to the session and then reconstitute the object by re-instantiating the class and then rehydrating the properties from a $_SESSION variable. You just do $_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cartObj); [See this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Comment: That's what was screwing me up originally then. I started out trying to use an object but had errors because the object had methods. I finally ended up doing this, 

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v) {
     if ($v == $itemID)
          unset($_SESSION['cart'][$k]);
}
which works, but I'm still wondering why I was getting the conversion error with array_diff();

Comment: Do a `print_r(array_diff($_SESSION['cart'], $items));` like I suggested earlier. I bet it does not look deep enough into the arrays to do what you hoped.

Comment: You might try `array_diff($_SESSION['cart'][], $items)` that might work.

Comment: I tried the print_r like you suggested above and it throws the same array to string conversion error.

Comment: And if I do `print_r(array_diff($_SESSION['cart'][], $items));`I get an error that says Fatal Error: Cannot use [] for reading in...

Answer (score 1):

i suggest this approach

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

to add an item

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item]= $qty;
```

then use the items id to manipulate:

delete:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item]);
```

change to known qty value:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item]= $qty;
```

add one:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item] += 1;
```

multiple variables for an item:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$item]= array('qty'=>$qty,$descrip,$size,$colour);
```

Comment: And using this method, how would you add additional variables, i.e. $price, $descr, etc.?